# Local properties of a topological space can be phrased in terms of local base

Tags: general-topology, locally-connected

I've been reviewing some local definitions of topological spaces, like locally compact space, locally connected space, etc. It seems that such properties can be phrased in terms of a local base, but I was wondering whether these properties can be phrased in terms of a topological basis.

For example, can we say that $X$ is locally compact if and only if it has a compact basis (consisting of compact sets)?

Comment: This is interesting. I have seen in another post someone comment we should call a property local if it is valid for a neighborhood base of a point, and regionao if it is valid for a neighborhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that a Hausdorff space $X$ is locally compact iff it has a base of *relatively* compact sets (so sets whose closure is compact), not of compact sets, because sets in a base have to open by definition (and in many spaces this implies they cannot be compact too, e.g. in Hausdorff connected spaces).

For locally connected spaces we can say that it has a base of connected subsets (it sort of depends on your definition of local connectedness, but this is true in most cases).

This is because the union of all local bases is a base and every base contains a local base for each of its points.

Comment: Two follow up questions if you would agree to it:
(1) Is the characterization of local properties by a local base true in general?
(2) You're saying that locally compact space does not necessarily mean a basis whose closure is compact ?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur “a base whose closure is compact”  is nonsense. It’s a base all of whose members have compact closure. And for non-Hausdorff spaces there are other non-equivalent definitions, so you have to be careful. For locally path connected, the base characterisation is more subtle. What other local properties do you know?

Comment: That's what I meant, despite not phrasing it correctly. I know of locally euclidean spaces, locally contarctible spaces, locally metrizable space etc. I was just wondering if all those can be characterized in the terms of local bases.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur those three, yes. But why would you prefer a global characterisation for a local property?

Comment: Trying to generalize it in my head, and hopefully for it to be correct.